# я в начале кода создал 3 переменые, как их можно вызвать в функциях

Tags: python

я делаю телеграм бота в начале кода я создал 3 переменые как я могу их вызвать в функциях?

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(токен)
counter = 0
const = 500
const_number = 500

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, введи число до 1000')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def game(message):
    number = int(message.text)
    while True:
        const_number = const_number // 2
        if const == number:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваше число {const} я угадал число за {counter} попыток')
            break
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваше число больше {const} ?')
            @bot.message_handler(content_types=['да'])
            def true(message1):


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Ну я вот вижу, что две вызываешь, хоть и ошибка будет.  В чем вопрос тогда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как я могу их вызвать в функциях?

Никак. **Вызывают** функции. Переменные **используют**.

Использовать любую переменную можно в её области видимости. Если переменная определена в самом начале программы, вне любого блока, то её можно использовать в любом месте программы, так как она видна везде. Если она не переопределена внутри какого-то блока.

Однако, в Python использование такой глобальной переменной внутри любого блока (например - функции) разделяется на два типа:

1. Чтение значения переменной
2. Присвоение нового значения переменной.

Для первого пункта ничего делать не нужно. Если же вы **внутри** блока собираетесь менять значение глобальной переменной, то Вы должны явно сказать об этом интерпретатору питона оператором *global*. Например, в Вашем случае, это должно выглядеть так:

```
def game(message):
    global const_number
    . . .
    const_number = const_number + 1
```